# Vuetify3: Failed to resolve component: v-speed-dial

Tags: vuetifyjs3

I am using Vuetify 3 with Vue 3 and Vite. The following code gives the above error v-speed-dial could not be resolved:

```
<v-speed-dial v-model="fab" bottom right>
   <template v-slot:activator>
      <v-btn v-model="fab" color="blue darken-2" dark fab>
         <v-icon v-if="fab">
            mdi-close
         </v-icon>
       <v-icon v-else>
         mdi-account-circle
       </v-icon>
      </v-btn>
     </template>
     <v-btn fab dark small color="green">
       <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
     </v-btn>
     <v-btn fab dark small color="indigo">
       <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
     </v-btn>
     <v-btn fab dark small color="red">
       <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
     </v-btn>
   </v-speed-dial>
```

The v-btn outside the template are shown, so v-btn is resolved, and `node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSpeedDial` exists.

Answer (score 0):

As of Vuetify 3.2, `v-speed-dial` is not yet available. Check [the task on GitHub](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/13508) for updates

Comment: I see . Are there similare restrictions for fab buttons? I was hoping to use v-espeed-dial to control the location of a fab button. My fab button always appears bottom left even if I set the options top right. The objective is to have a fab button that always stays close to the lower right of the visible area and can be used to scroll to top. I had it with Vuetify 2 bit it broke with Vuetify 3. It would be great if someone had such a component for re-use.